# What is the minimum amount of data required in order to send a packet?

Tags: c, packet

First a little background: I have an idea for a chat application. I don't want the user to need to put in connection details, so I was thinking I can send a custom ethernet packet type. That packet is received by peers; generating a database of every peer within the user's application. I don't want to overcomplicate generating my raw packets. What is the minimum amount of data required in order to send a successfully received packet? Do any special circumstances exist where a minimal packet will transmit properly with some hardware, and not other hardware?

Let me clarify, and be explicit: I am asking what is the minimum amount of information required *in the packet* for that packet to be transmitted, and received. An example of information that can be found in an ethernet packet is an IP address, a hardware address, time-to-live, et cetera.

Comment: why do you overcomplicate your life? use portable protocols, e.g. TCP

Comment: It's more of a programming challenge for me. I can just as easily use an existing chat program or service if I wanted it to be easy.

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for multicast IP

Comment: It seems very clear to me what the user is asking. Essentially they want the required parts of the IP protocol to deliver a packet (for their specific use case).  Yes, there may be a better answer (there most certainly is), but this question is interesting and answerable, even if it's not advisable.

Comment: @SeanPedersen What level of the protocol stack are you working at ? If you want to send ethernet frames, the minimum ethernet payload size is 46 bytes. (But ethernet is not reliable, nor can you send ethernet frames outside your local network). If you want to send IP packets, they have a minimum payload length of 0 bytes (But are not reliable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the mimimum amount of data required in order to send a
>   successfully received packet?

You don't need to use IP at all if you aren't going to send this over the internet.
On your LAN you could get by with a custom network layer if you like.
There are also existing nonip protocols (IPX) which may be suiting your needs. IPX is relatively simple to set up but people will be mad at you if they ever catch you using it.
(I also have no idea if windows supports IPX since winxp).
That would be the hard way.

The easier way would be to use UDP/IP. UDP is designed to be minimal.
The wiki page for UDP will tell you the header size of a UDP datagram.
Don't forget to add the IP header (wiki again) and ethernet frame (ibid.) to this.
Finally you need a payload.

There are many many options. It depends largely on the network infrastructure you intend to use. If your infrastructure is IP over Ethernet then you'll be stuck with that!

> Do any special circumstances exist where a minimal packet will
>   transmit properly with some hardware, and not other hardware?
>   If you adhere to the standards: No. If you flaunt the standards: Very probably.

In your latter question you seem to be hinting you would like to employ 'clever' tricks to minimize packet size (ie, missing out non-critical parts of the header(s)), but I repeat: DO NOT GO AGAINST THE STANDARDS.
People will be very very dissapointed with you if the catch you doing this and you will lose all your friends.

Comment: The multicast IP (used with UDP of course) is also a good suggestion by Flexo. This will save replicating gazillions of packets in your peer based protocol. All your peers could be on the same multicast address and then the switches will do all the work for you.